# Next.js automatic class completion for CSS modules in WebStorm?

Tags: reactjs, webstorm, css-modules, react-css-modules

Is there any way to add automatic class completion for CSS modules in IntelliJ IDEA's apps?

I use WebStorm and currently developing a project on Next.js (React).

I used to write something like `div.avatar` and press the TAB key so IDE will convert my code to `<div class="avatar"></div>`. I wonder whether this is possible for CSS modules because right now, I need to rewrite each CSS class manually.

[image]

Comment: *"I used to write something like div.avatar and press the TAB key so IDE will convert my code to <div class="avatar"></div>"* That's a **standard Emmet functionality**. You cannot customize such behaviour.

Comment: This ticket seems to be what you are after: consider watching it (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-52596

Comment: @LazyOne Thank you, this is exactly what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I used to write something like `div.avatar` and press the TAB key so IDE will convert my code to `<div class="avatar"></div>`

That's a [standard Emmet functionality](https://docs.emmet.io/abbreviations/syntax/). You cannot customize this behaviour in WebStorm.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-52596 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress. *I suggest you do that so the devs know that it's a needed functionality (to bump the priority: no votes means no users interested in this)*.